# Photoshop CS6 Size of Objects

Tags: size, photoshop

I'm using PS CS6 and have almost no experiences with Photoshop. I just need to get some sizes in pixels to create HTML.

Maybe a trivial question, but couldn't find any answer on Google and stackoverflow.

Problem:
The main image consists of different layers. Those layers contain an image. How do I get the size of those images in pixels? I could use the ruler but there has to be a much more simple way. Any idea?

Please assist me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
For Single image (sub-Image)

Select or click on Image than look under menu of cs6 you can show [Show Transform Control] check it and you can re-size your image in any size.

For Whole Image
PS>Image > Image Size > Give Wight and Height in Pixel so u can use that image as HTML file.

Hope It will be work

Regards
Dhruvil

Comment: Tick mark it right when you know this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

for images or other objects on a layer show the info palette (F8) and select the object as if you wanted to resize it (eg click upper right corner). The dimensions of the image are then displayed in the info palette.

Answer (score 0):

In PS CS6 simply make a rectangle and you have shown its size next to the cursor. Before this make sure that you have pixels as your main unit in preferences.

Good Luck.